# whereraw Vs DB::raw in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am confused and really don't know how and where should I choose to use one from both ?

I read docs for both

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses

And

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#raw-expressions

If I use query something like this its not working

```
DB::table('table_name')
->where('parent_id', $parent_id)
->whereRaw("date",">",$date)
->get();
```

But it works

```
DB::table('table_name')
->where('parent_id', $parent_id)
->where(DB::raw("date",">",$date))
->get();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`DB::raw()` lets you write raw statements as a part of the query. Eg:

```
->where(DB::raw('DATE(date_column)'), '>', '2017-01-01')
```

But if you need to write a complete "raw *where*", you should use `whereRaw` (for your convenience). Eg:

```
->whereRaw('DATE(date_column) > DATE(another_date_column)')
```

Also, `whereRaw()` accepts a complete where clause.

So, in your first example it's not working, because you should do it:

```
->whereRaw("date > ".$date)
```

And your second example could be simplified by using just `whereRaw()` like the above statement in my answer.

Also `DB::raw()` can be used in `->select()`,`groupBy()` and others.

Comment: I would also add that whereRaw can also accept an array of parameters as a second argument (just like DB::raw())
Ex: ->whereRaw("date > ?", [$date])